# VSCode remote ssh: Can't install extensions on remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to install an extension (as an example cmake tools) on my remote server (ubuntu Arm 64). I have enabled remote.downloadExtensionsLocally feature). When I try to install the extensions, it seems downloaded locally but can't be installed on the target server.

**My Host:** Windows 10

**My Server:** Ubuntu 64 ARM running on a rasp4

Here are my user settings (I have enabled a proxy. no diff with/without proxy):
[image]

and here are my remote settings:
[image]

and this is my windows trace logs after clicking on install button (As can be seen the extension has downloaded successfully):
[image]

and my remote server log:
[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_advanced-forcing-an-extension-to-run-locally-remotely

Comment: @rioV8 I have already read that doc . No help. I guess the problem is related to my server

Comment: There is a problem that vsc can't copy the extension to server. It's weird that it doesn't give any errors in log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your Linux kernel/version is compatible with the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux). I guess that the requirements on your server are not met. Please check them:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the issue by upgrading my ubuntu on the server!